# CSS make div 100% width relevant to body and not it's parent div

Tags: html, css, width

I have

```
<div style="position:relative; width:500px;">
    <div style="position:absolute; width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

The child div takes 100% width of it's parent div. Is there a way i can force it to take 100% width of body and not the parent div. Both relative and absolute positioning are required as i have it in the code above.

Comment: Without JS update on CSS, I think you can only do this to fixed elements `position: fixed;` :(

Comment: I don't think there is a way to have the child div take the width of body since it inherits from the parent. However, there is probably a way to achieve what you want. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve? a jsfiddle would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this while keeping the relative and absolute positioning as you have in your code is to use JavaScript.  You need to get window width and set that as the div width. You also need to detect window size on resize so you always have your div adjust set to the current window width.

The other 2 ways you can do this may not be options for but worth mentioning

1. Put the child div outside the parent div.
2. Or set it to fixed position. Doing this may not give a desirable effect. The div will always be in the same position regardless of page scroll.

Answer (score 4):

Modern browsers have [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) for [viewport units](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/).

```css
header {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

nav {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
  <html>
  <body>
  
  <header>
    <p>This inherits the width of the parent like normal.</p>
    
    <nav>
      <a href="/">this fills the viewport</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

###### Nowerdays you can make sth relative to the viewport via

#### viewport width `vw`

#### viewport height `vh`

##### whichever is larger `vmax`

##### whichever is smaller `vmin`

This may be an alternative for many.

*In case anyone will ever stumble upon this thread again :)*