# getting an inner div width relative to body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to edit bootstrap dropdown to my liking but having problem with setting the dropdown-menu width, need it to have 80% of body width which cannot use width: 80% because it's father ain't the body.

I've tried: width: 80%; width: 80vw;

second one works but is not responsive. 
first one makes 80% relative to the father div (the one with btn-group class)

```
<div class="btn-group float-right pt-2 pr-5 ">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark pl-4 py-2 dropdown-toggle city_btn" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="ml-3"></span> <i class="fas ml-2 fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span class="cityactive">0</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu mydropdownoptions">
    <span class="mydropdownitems">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <a class="" href="#">1</a>
    </span>
    <span class="mydropdownitems">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <a class="" href="#">2</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also post your current css

Comment: this may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948305/css-make-div-100-width-relevant-to-body-and-not-its-parent-div